# Process when reading files from directory with php then showing them in my html file

Tags: php, html

I use php files in my website and in those file I include my html to show whatever i want the user to view. However i've ran into a problem. I need to show a list of available downloads from a specific folder from my website. The uploading downloadables from my website works. The reading files from directory works, this is done using php code. Now the thing is how can I show this in my html, how to I show this to my user in a fashion that i like most, like for example how Dropbox shows their file listing something like that.

The thing is to pass those files found within the PHP file and pass them to the html to be able to work with them however I want.

I hope i am clear, in case please just tell me so I can elaborate more.

Thanks.

Some code as requested, this is how I am supposedly extracting my files from my website's directory...

Ahh something like this, i get the idea, but here is my problem...

my code looks like this...

```
$directory_mine;


    if ($directory_mine = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
//This is for testing.
echo "Directory: ". $directory_mine . "\n";
echo "Entries:\n";

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($directory_mine))) {

    //should be writing each file name into the html here. at least thats my thinking.

}

closedir($directory_mine);
    }
    include("overall_header.html");
    include("mobiledownloadview.html");
    include("overall_footer.html");
```

See here is the problem, how can i add the data extracted by my php file to the mobiledownloadview.html???
I believe this is one way to do it, but if this is terrible please tell me. is there a better way to acomplish my goal?

Comment: Pretend you're in fifth grade and Stack is the teacher that says, "Show your work!"

Comment: my bad.. didnt know that this code was necessary since all I am doing is extracting the files that are in a specific directory... what i wanted to know is how to pass those files that the PHP is giving me to the HTML so I can show them in a nice way.

Comment: RTFM, your code seems to come straight from it...

Comment: I know i just  added it to give an idea of what i meant.

Comment: @Steven Hernandez Then what is the problem exactly, the styling?

Comment: My problem is not reading the directory, my problem is using it in my html that i include in my php. So that i can style them in my own way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual on [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php):

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

If you want to style it, wrap it in an (un-) ordered list and use css for that.

Comment: what if i have my html already included at the end of my php file, how can i do then?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($entry = readdir($directory_mine)) !== false) {
      echo "Entry: $entry ; filetype: " . filetype($directory_mine . $entry) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3+, the PHP SPL class `FilesystemIterator` could be useful in this case, it easily allows iterating over a certain path and retrieving files as objects, including metadata.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php

Example:

```
<?php
$it = new FilesystemIterator($directory_mine);
echo '<ul class="file_list">'
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    echo  '<li>' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</ul>'
```

You can add CSS to the page to style the unordered list how you want it to appear.

Comment: Ahh something like this, still kind of a problem to add it to my html files that are included at the end of my php file. check the code above, i edited it of how it actually looks.

Comment: If those HTML files are evaluated as PHP, you can assign the HTML to a variable and output it from a PHP tag in the file. Otherwise, rename mobiledownload.html to mobiledownload.php and then add the above code to it in the spot where you want the download list to be.

Comment: i figure it out, i didnt realize that i could extract data, and that whatever html is included in that particular php, whatever variables are there stored can be used in the html, but writing as a php script...the trick is editting the htaccess file to add type php, so the php script runs in the html files.